# 3.5mm to Sony LBT D107

Tags: speakers, equipment

I'd like to connect my iPhone to my Sony LBT D107 as an input source. I'm no technician, but:

1) What's the most affordable way to this?

2) What sort of connection will provide the best quality output?

The rest of the internet is indecisive and so far, mostly unhelpful. I checked the Help section and hopefully this question isn't off-topic (maybe more appropriate for SoundDesign.se?). Let me know if I can supply you with any more information.

Update: I have an iPhone XR, so technically I have a lightning port, however I have a lightning to 3.5mm and assumed this would be easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference it would be helpful to specify the connectors on the gear you're referring to. I'll assume your phone has a lightning connector and I looked up the Sony LBT D107, which has several pairs of stereo RCA inputs.

You want a lightning-to-stereo pair male RCA cable if such a thing exists (doubtful!) or lightning to 3.5mm stereo cable (plentiful!) then 3.5mm stereo female to RCA stereo pair male cable (plentiful!).

Anything that's not the cheapest possible dollar-store cable should suffice. Use the "CD" or "Video" inputs on the LBT D107, not the "Phono" input.

Good luck!

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments (thank you!), OP indicated 3.5mm in the title. So just 3.5mm stereo female to RCA stereo pair male cable.

Comment: Q title says 3.5mm, so I'd just google "iphone headphone to rca cable" If you remove 'headphone' from that term then lightning adapters are first in results.

Comment: Welcome:) I'd specifically include 'iPhone' in the search just to prevent wrong pin-out results… remember Sony's laptop AV pin-out?? ;-))